# Valid JSON But can't parse it in my javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to get the information of a product in amazon.com using their Product API.

There is 2 page. First page uploads a file containing the ASIN codes to another page and it is using malsup jquery form plugin to do it. The other page uses the API to get the response and convert it into json using php json_encode function and return back to the first page.

First page:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
{
var options = { 
    beforeSend: function() 
    {
        $("#progress").show();
        //clear everything
        $("#progress").width('0%');
        $("#progress").text('0%');

    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
    {
        $("#progress").css('width',percentComplete+'%');
        $("#progress").text(percentComplete+'%');

    },
    success: function() 
    {
        $("#progress").width('100%');
        $("#progress").text('0%');

    },
    complete: function(response) 
    {

        var restext = response.responseText;
        var links = JSON.parse(restext);
        console.log(JSON.parse(links));
         $("#message").html("<font color='green'>"+links[0]+"</font>");
        // alert(links[1].Items.Item.DetailPageURL);
        links.forEach(function(link){
            alert(link.Items.Item.ASIN);
        var results = link.Items.Item.ItemLinks.ItemLink; //array
        results.forEach(function(result){
            $("#description").append("<h3 color='green'>"+result.Description+"</h3> \n<a href='"+result.URL+"'>"+result.URL+"</a>");
            // $("#URLS").append("<p color='green'>"+result.URL+"</p>");
        });
        alert()
            $("#ASIN").append("<p color='green'>"+link.Items.Item.ASIN+"</p>");
            $('#mainurltext').show();
            $("#mainurl").append("<a href='"+link.Items.Item.DetailPageURL+"'>"+link.Items.Item.DetailPageURL+"</a>");

            $("#image").append("<img src='"+link.Items.Item.LargeImage.URL+"' width='375' height-'500' />");
        });
        // $("#message").html("<font color='green'>"+result[0].URL+"</font>");
    },
    error: function()
    {
        $("#message").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");

    },

    dataType:  "json",

     }

     $("#productform").ajaxForm(options);


});
</script>
```

Second page using api and returning JSON:

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use ApaiIO\Configuration\GenericConfiguration;
use ApaiIO\Operations\Search;
use ApaiIO\ApaiIO;
use ApaiIO\Operations\Lookup;

function scrape($info)
{
$conf = new GenericConfiguration();
$conf
    ->setCountry('com')
    ->setAccessKey("API KEY")
    ->setSecretKey('API SECRET')
    ->setAssociateTag('ASSOCIATE TAG');
$apaiIo = new ApaiIO($conf);
$lookup = new Lookup();
$lookup->setItemId($info); //B00D6BN9NK
$lookup->setResponseGroup(array('Large')); // More detailed information
$response = $apaiIo->runOperation($lookup);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response) or die('Cannot create xml element');
$json = json_encode($xml);

return $json;
}





if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if(isset($_FILES['infofile']))
{
if($_FILES['infofile']['error'] > 0)
{
echo "<pre>Error ". $_FILES['infofile']['error'] . " </pre>";
}else{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['infofile']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['infofile']['name']);
}
}
$lines = file("uploads/".$_FILES['infofile']['name'],FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$items = "";
foreach($lines as $line)
{
$items .= scrape($line) . ",";
}
$items = rtrim($items,",");
$items = "[".$items."]";
echo json_encode($items);
}
```

But the problem is i can't parse json. When i use var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText) and  console.log(json[0]); it is logging the first character instead of the first object.

Console..log(json) is outputting:

```
[{"OperationRequest":{"HTTPHeaders":{"0":{"@attributes":{"Name":"UserAgent","Value":"ApaiIO [2.0.0-DEV]"}}},"RequestId":"7a5bf557-5b04-4685-be67-094c970bdf8b","Arguments":{"Argument":[{"@attributes":{"Name":"AWSAccessKeyId","Value":"AKIAIBYRBZRR7WVI3CMQ"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"AssociateTag","Value":"heyadme-20"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"ItemId","Value":"B00D6BN9NK"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Operation","Value":"ItemLookup"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"ResponseGroup","Value":"Large"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Service","Value":"AWSECommerceService"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Timestamp","Value":"2015-10-02T18:30:08Z"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Version","Value":"2011-08-01"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Signature","Value":"ilDCR1xAoQLM8cUAixQUt\/0z5QoWDJqL2LUtD5cDB2g="}}]},"RequestProcessingTime":"0.0874180000000000"},"Items":{"Request":{"IsValid":"True","ItemLookupRequest":{"IdType":"ASIN","ItemId":"B00D6BN9NK","ResponseGroup":"Large","VariationPage":"All"}},"Item":{"ASIN":"B00D6BN9NK","DetailPageURL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/A-Good-Day-Die-Hard\/dp\/B00D6BN9NK%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIA…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00D6BN9NK","ItemLinks":{"ItemLink":[{"Description":"Technical Details","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/A-Good-Day-Die-Hard\/dp\/tech-data\/B00D6BN9NK%3FSubscripti…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00D6BN9NK"},{"Description":"Add To Baby Registry","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/registry\/baby\/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB00D6BN9NK%26S…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00D6BN9NK"},{"Description":"Add To Wedding Registry","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/registry\/wedding\/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB00D6BN9NK%…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00D6BN9NK"},{"Description":"Add To Wishlist","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/registry\/wishlist\/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB00D6BN9NK…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00D6BN9NK"},{"Description":"Tell A Friend","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/pdp\/taf\/B00D6BN9NK%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIBYRBZRR7WV…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00D6BN9NK"},{"Description":"All Customer Reviews","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/review\/product\/B00D6BN9NK%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIBYRBZRR…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00D6BN9NK"},{"Description":"All Offers","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/offer-listing\/B00D6BN9NK%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIBYRBZ…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00D6BN9NK"}]},"SmallImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51TOcIFX%2BVL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"56"},"MediumImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51TOcIFX%2BVL._SL160_.jpg","Height":"160","Width":"120"},"LargeImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51TOcIFX%2BVL.jpg","Height":"500","Width":"375"},"ImageSets":{"ImageSet":{"@attributes":{"Category":"primary"},"SwatchImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51TOcIFX%2BVL._SL30_.jpg","Height":"30","Width":"22"},"SmallImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51TOcIFX%2BVL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"56"},"ThumbnailImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51TOcIFX%2BVL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"56"},"TinyImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51TOcIFX%2BVL._SL110_.jpg","Height":"110","Width":"82"},"MediumImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51TOcIFX%2BVL._SL160_.jpg","Height":"160","Width":"120"},"LargeImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51TOcIFX%2BVL.jpg","Height":"500","Width":"375"}}},"ItemAttributes":{"Actor":["Bruce Willis","Jai Courtney","Sebastian Koch","Rasha Bukvic","Cole Hauser"],"AudienceRating":"R (Restricted)","Binding":"Amazon Instant Video","Director":"John Moore","Genre":"Action","Languages":{"Language":[{"Name":"English","Type":"Subtitled"},{"Name":"English","Type":"Unknown"}]},"ProductGroup":"Movie","ProductTypeName":"DOWNLOADABLE_MOVIE","ReleaseDate":"2015-09-11","RunningTime":"98","Studio":"Fox","Title":"A Good Day to Die Hard"},"OfferSummary":{"LowestNewPrice":{"Amount":"299","CurrencyCode":"USD","FormattedPrice":"$2.99"},"TotalNew":"1","TotalUsed":"0","TotalCollectible":"0","TotalRefurbished":"0"},"Offers":{"TotalOffers":"1","TotalOfferPages":"1","MoreOffersUrl":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/offer-listing\/B00D6BN9NK%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIBYRBZ…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00D6BN9NK","Offer":{"OfferAttributes":{"Condition":"New"},"OfferListing":{"OfferListingId":"jz9ClzBQvnwulA5JO%2FG01g%2BOlezQ77ZsP3jCkxm3Hz8Xah%2Bpk7Vq%2FhLk5d6cfXJYdZqaOo%2FX3lGnrsrt54DkqQdYwuYSwALKXpzsC9wgDCH5mKMozevD4hmIPlMaJjNkN%2Bm11nUqRDFydPEIfcYFyN5EW01GQ7to","Price":{"Amount":"299","CurrencyCode":"USD","FormattedPrice":"$2.99"},"Availability":"Usually ships in 1-2 business days","AvailabilityAttributes":{"AvailabilityType":"now","MinimumHours":"24","MaximumHours":"48"},"IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping":"0","IsEligibleForPrime":"0"}}},"CustomerReviews":{"IFrameURL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/reviews\/iframe?akid=AKIAIBYRBZRR7WVI3CMQ&alinkCode=xm2&asi…-03T06%3A00%3A21Z&v=2&sig=HGZbLdRlswUpuZj3i%2FPqUa0EyuV90Mb990WGO9xtn4A%3D","HasReviews":"true"},"SimilarProducts":{"SimilarProduct":[{"ASIN":"B0011MZOEI","Title":"Live Free or Die Hard"},{"ASIN":"B00AGDX2F6","Title":"Die Hard 2: Die Harder"},{"ASIN":"B001FVD65O","Title":"Die Hard: With a Vengeance"},{"ASIN":"B004Z1IKCK","Title":"Die Hard: With a Vengeance"},{"ASIN":"B000SZK41M","Title":"Die Hard"}]},"BrowseNodes":{"BrowseNode":[{"BrowseNodeId":"2649512011","Name":"Movies","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2625374011","Name":"Departments","IsCategoryRoot":"1","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2625373011","Name":"Movies & TV"}}}}},{"BrowseNodeId":"2858905011","Name":"Movies","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2858778011","Name":"Amazon Video","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2644982011","Name":"Custom Stores","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2644981011","Name":"Specialty Stores","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2625373011","Name":"Movies & TV"}}}}}}}}},{"BrowseNodeId":"2958762011","Name":"Action & Adventure","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2958761011","Name":"Genre for Featured Categories","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2644982011","Name":"Custom Stores","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2644981011","Name":"Specialty Stores","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2625373011","Name":"Movies & TV"}}}}}}}}},{"BrowseNodeId":"277825011","Name":"Compatible Devices","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2998370011","Name":"AIV Custom Stores","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2644982011","Name":"Custom Stores","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2644981011","Name":"Specialty Stores","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"2625373011","Name":"Movies & TV"}}}}}}}}}]}}}},{"OperationRequest":{"HTTPHeaders":{"0":{"@attributes":{"Name":"UserAgent","Value":"ApaiIO [2.0.0-DEV]"}}},"RequestId":"028a0fc0-c52e-4d19-b831-c1337aff724e","Arguments":{"Argument":[{"@attributes":{"Name":"AWSAccessKeyId","Value":"AKIAIBYRBZRR7WVI3CMQ"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"AssociateTag","Value":"heyadme-20"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"ItemId","Value":"B00CCHBA8U"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Operation","Value":"ItemLookup"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"ResponseGroup","Value":"Large"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Service","Value":"AWSECommerceService"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Timestamp","Value":"2015-10-02T18:30:09Z"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Version","Value":"2011-08-01"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Signature","Value":"4tT70GT20eszPG6BbOUgbJZnJFr66wgLRr\/A4ttX2Cw="}}]},"RequestProcessingTime":"0.0287780000000000"},"Items":{"Request":{"IsValid":"True","ItemLookupRequest":{"IdType":"ASIN","ItemId":"B00CCHBA8U","ResponseGroup":"Large","VariationPage":"All"}},"Item":{"ASIN":"B00CCHBA8U","DetailPageURL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/SHEER-NO2-Supplement-Top-Rated-Guarantee\/dp\/B00CCHBA8U%3F…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00CCHBA8U","ItemLinks":{"ItemLink":[{"Description":"Technical Details","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/SHEER-NO2-Supplement-Top-Rated-Guarantee\/dp\/tech-data\/B0…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00CCHBA8U"},{"Description":"Add To Baby Registry","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/registry\/baby\/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB00CCHBA8U%26S…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00CCHBA8U"},{"Description":"Add To Wedding Registry","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/registry\/wedding\/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB00CCHBA8U%…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00CCHBA8U"},{"Description":"Add To Wishlist","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/registry\/wishlist\/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB00CCHBA8U…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00CCHBA8U"},{"Description":"Tell A Friend","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/pdp\/taf\/B00CCHBA8U%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIBYRBZRR7WV…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00CCHBA8U"},{"Description":"All Customer Reviews","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/review\/product\/B00CCHBA8U%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIBYRBZRR…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00CCHBA8U"},{"Description":"All Offers","URL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/offer-listing\/B00CCHBA8U%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIBYRBZ…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00CCHBA8U"}]},"SalesRank":"533","SmallImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51t-yqnE3sL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"75"},"MediumImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51t-yqnE3sL._SL160_.jpg","Height":"160","Width":"160"},"LargeImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51t-yqnE3sL.jpg","Height":"500","Width":"500"},"ImageSets":{"ImageSet":[{"@attributes":{"Category":"variant"},"SwatchImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41h8knclZoL._SL30_.jpg","Height":"23","Width":"30"},"SmallImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41h8knclZoL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"57","Width":"75"},"ThumbnailImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41h8knclZoL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"57","Width":"75"},"TinyImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41h8knclZoL._SL110_.jpg","Height":"84","Width":"110"},"MediumImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41h8knclZoL._SL160_.jpg","Height":"122","Width":"160"},"LargeImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41h8knclZoL.jpg","Height":"380","Width":"500"}},{"@attributes":{"Category":"variant"},"SwatchImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/412Kz4g-JXL._SL30_.jpg","Height":"23","Width":"30"},"SmallImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/412Kz4g-JXL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"57","Width":"75"},"ThumbnailImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/412Kz4g-JXL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"57","Width":"75"},"TinyImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/412Kz4g-JXL._SL110_.jpg","Height":"84","Width":"110"},"MediumImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/412Kz4g-JXL._SL160_.jpg","Height":"122","Width":"160"},"LargeImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/412Kz4g-JXL.jpg","Height":"380","Width":"500"}},{"@attributes":{"Category":"variant"},"SwatchImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41F-sRusupL._SL30_.jpg","Height":"23","Width":"30"},"SmallImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41F-sRusupL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"57","Width":"75"},"ThumbnailImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41F-sRusupL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"57","Width":"75"},"TinyImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41F-sRusupL._SL110_.jpg","Height":"84","Width":"110"},"MediumImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41F-sRusupL._SL160_.jpg","Height":"122","Width":"160"},"LargeImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41F-sRusupL.jpg","Height":"380","Width":"500"}},{"@attributes":{"Category":"variant"},"SwatchImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Ljcas4ikL._SL30_.jpg","Height":"30","Width":"30"},"SmallImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Ljcas4ikL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"75"},"ThumbnailImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Ljcas4ikL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"75"},"TinyImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Ljcas4ikL._SL110_.jpg","Height":"110","Width":"110"},"MediumImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Ljcas4ikL._SL160_.jpg","Height":"160","Width":"160"},"LargeImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Ljcas4ikL.jpg","Height":"500","Width":"500"}},{"@attributes":{"Category":"variant"},"SwatchImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61vZGtnnSiL._SL30_.jpg","Height":"30","Width":"30"},"SmallImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61vZGtnnSiL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"75"},"ThumbnailImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61vZGtnnSiL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"75"},"TinyImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61vZGtnnSiL._SL110_.jpg","Height":"110","Width":"110"},"MediumImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61vZGtnnSiL._SL160_.jpg","Height":"160","Width":"160"},"LargeImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61vZGtnnSiL.jpg","Height":"500","Width":"500"}},{"@attributes":{"Category":"variant"},"SwatchImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Fqhz0C6SL._SL30_.jpg","Height":"30","Width":"30"},"SmallImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Fqhz0C6SL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"75"},"ThumbnailImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Fqhz0C6SL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"75"},"TinyImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Fqhz0C6SL._SL110_.jpg","Height":"110","Width":"110"},"MediumImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Fqhz0C6SL._SL160_.jpg","Height":"160","Width":"160"},"LargeImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/61Fqhz0C6SL.jpg","Height":"500","Width":"500"}},{"@attributes":{"Category":"primary"},"SwatchImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51t-yqnE3sL._SL30_.jpg","Height":"30","Width":"30"},"SmallImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51t-yqnE3sL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"75"},"ThumbnailImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51t-yqnE3sL._SL75_.jpg","Height":"75","Width":"75"},"TinyImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51t-yqnE3sL._SL110_.jpg","Height":"110","Width":"110"},"MediumImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51t-yqnE3sL._SL160_.jpg","Height":"160","Width":"160"},"LargeImage":{"URL":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51t-yqnE3sL.jpg","Height":"500","Width":"500"}}]},"ItemAttributes":{"Binding":"Health and Beauty","Brand":"Sheer Strength Labs","EAN":"0820103175005","EANList":{"EANListElement":"0820103175005"},"Feature":["BUILD MUSCLE AND STRENGTH OR YOUR MONEY BACK! When Taken With A Good Workout Plan, Sheer Strength NO2 Is GUARANTEED To Increase Muscle Growth And Strength Or Your Money Back! You'll Feel It Kicking In And Adding Strength To Your Workouts Within The First Week. Simply The Best Nitric Oxide Supplements You've Ever Tried!","GOOD FOR YOUR HEART: L-Arginine Boosts Nitric Oxide Production For Fast Muscle Building, A Healthy Heart, and Fast Muscle Growth. Nitric Oxide Increases Workout Performance, Giving You The Best Muscle Pump You've Ever Had, As Well As Increasing Blood Flow From The Heart To Every Area Of The Body.","#1 TOP RATED FORMULA: Sheer Strength NO2 Is The ONLY Popular Nitric Oxide Booster That Contains L Citrulline, One Of Nature's Most Powerful NO2 Boosters. As A Result, You Get The Best Workout You've Ever Had From The Biggest Nitric Oxide Booster You've Ever Imagined!","BOOST MALE PERFORMANCE: Because Sheer Strength NO2 Increases Blood Flow To The Muscles, It Gives You A Blood Flow Post To \"Other\" Areas Of The Body As Well. The Ladies Will Notice - Trust Us, You'll Feel It.","30-DAY 100% MONEY BACK GUARANTEE - Return Even The Empty Bottles! We're So Confident That You'll Love Sheer Strength NO2 That We'll Refund Every Penny If You Don't Like It! What Do You Have To Lose? You'll Either Add Muscle And Increase Performance, Or You'll Lose Nothing."],"Label":"Sheer Strengths Labs","ListPrice":{"Amount":"4999","CurrencyCode":"USD","FormattedPrice":"$49.99"},"Manufacturer":"Sheer Strengths Labs","PackageDimensions":{"Height":"280","Length":"560","Weight":"40","Width":"290"},"PackageQuantity":"1","ProductGroup":"Health and Beauty","ProductTypeName":"HEALTH_PERSONAL_CARE","Publisher":"Sheer Strengths Labs","Studio":"Sheer Strengths Labs","Title":"SHEER NO2: #1 Best Nitric Oxide Supplement \u25cf The Top-Rated Nitric Oxide Booster from Sheer Strength Labs \u25cf Build Muscle and Strength Or It's Free: 30-Day 'Thrilled Customer' 100% Guarantee!","UPC":"820103175005","UPCList":{"UPCListElement":"820103175005"}},"OfferSummary":{"LowestNewPrice":{"Amount":"2897","CurrencyCode":"USD","FormattedPrice":"$28.97"},"TotalNew":"3","TotalUsed":"0","TotalCollectible":"0","TotalRefurbished":"0"},"Offers":{"TotalOffers":"1","TotalOfferPages":"1","MoreOffersUrl":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/gp\/offer-listing\/B00CCHBA8U%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIBYRBZ…nkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00CCHBA8U","Offer":{"OfferAttributes":{"Condition":"New"},"OfferListing":{"OfferListingId":"5VwspO4u6OeAyJa4bmxDQYHPX1ciZrmTun9TFOkY2Vc7Ie7tM26%2BnlZbnjCcrARqH9DbNeH4oH6SZfOJjiXztuZQe4T45r0cgXoObB5CxAI5QHA8lv6qLZfdhDzBNW2CTyLM4BRH2kktc62jGUSt7Q%3D%3D","Price":{"Amount":"2897","CurrencyCode":"USD","FormattedPrice":"$28.97"},"AmountSaved":{"Amount":"2102","CurrencyCode":"USD","FormattedPrice":"$21.02"},"PercentageSaved":"42","Availability":"Usually ships in 24 hours","AvailabilityAttributes":{"AvailabilityType":"now","MinimumHours":"0","MaximumHours":"0"},"IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping":"1","IsEligibleForPrime":"1"}}},"CustomerReviews":{"IFrameURL":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/reviews\/iframe?akid=AKIAIBYRBZRR7WVI3CMQ&alinkCode=xm2&asi…-03T06%3A00%3A22Z&v=2&sig=3cE3oKNNqXv8nRZIi4UvzMrDgQhXo%2BhfqdlN8rHAtNo%3D","HasReviews":"true"},"EditorialReviews":{"EditorialReview":{"Source":"Product Description","Content":"<p><b>Are Nitric Oxide Supplements The Secret To Muscle Growth and Performance?<\/b><\/p> \n<p>\"I've tried about all there is to try to gain a competitive edge as far as supplements go. 'Sheer Strength' is one of the best I have taken without the nasty side effects or jitters.\" \u00ad Nithanial Decker<\/p> \n<p>\"Within a month, everyone could see a difference in my physique. The difference is amazing!\" - From Recent Reviews<\/p> \n<p>As the #1-rated nitric oxide supplement used by athletes, bodybuilders, and healthy people everywhere, Sheer Strength NO2 <b>boosts muscle growth<\/b> while being good for your heart and immune system. Sheer Strength NO2 helps your body produce more nitric oxide, giving you <b>more energy, more explosiveness, a healthy heart, and boosted strength<\/b>. <\/p> \n<p>This nitric oxide booster contains ingredients that are involved in \"wound healing, helping the kidneys remove waste products from the body, [and] maintaining immune and hormone function.\" They have also been featured on TV as a powerful and natural way to increase reps and strength in the gym.<\/p> \n<p>At Sheer Strength Labs, we give you the maximum active ingredients and less of the junk that your body doesn't need. <b>Our challenge: Take one bottle for thirty days. If you don't gain muscle, feel stronger, and have more energy, we'll buy it back from you!<\/b> But keep your new muscles as a THANK YOU for trying it out.<\/p> \n<p><b>Money Back Guarantee:<\/b> if you aren't thrilled with the results that you get from Sheer Strength NO2, simply return the product (even the empty bottles) to Amazon for a full money back guarantee.<\/p>","IsLinkSuppressed":"0"}},"SimilarProducts":{"SimilarProduct":[{"ASIN":"B00KGOCK5S","Title":"SHEER STRENGTH BCAA Capsules - Burn Fat and Build Muscle Now With The Best Branch Chain Amino Acid Supplement - Full 30 Day Supply"},{"ASIN":"B00H4IBD0M","Title":"SHEER TESTOSTERONE - #1 Best Testosterone Booster With Fenugreek \u25cf 100% Natural Testosterone Booster for Men \u25cf Science-Backed Formula Naturally Builds Muscle, Burns Fat, and Boosts Male Performance"},{"ASIN":"B00UVXQ9Q0","Title":"SHEER ALPHA: The Best Testosterone Booster For Men \u25cf FINALLY Get The Body You Want With The #1 Top-Rated Muscle Builder Supplement on Amazon - 100% Natural Science-Based Formula Delivers REAL Results"},{"ASIN":"B00QETHBP8","Title":"Sheer Strength Labs Creatine Monohydrate - 500g - 100 Servings"},{"ASIN":"B00N48DV92","Title":"SHEER THERMO: The #1 Best Fat Burning Thermogenic Supplement \u25cf Proven Science-Based Formula With Yohimbe + Yohimbine +More \u25cf Burn Fat and Lose Weight Fast With The Most Effective Fat Burner Available"}]},"BrowseNodes":{"BrowseNode":[{"BrowseNodeId":"6973678011","Name":"Supplements","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"6973669011","Name":"Endurance & Energy","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"6973663011","Name":"Sports Nutrition","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"3760931","Name":"Products","IsCategoryRoot":"1","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"3760901","Name":"Health & Personal Care"}}}}}}}}},{"BrowseNodeId":"6973698011","Name":"Nitric Oxide Boosters","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"6973697011","Name":"Pre-Workout","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"6973663011","Name":"Sports Nutrition","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"3760931","Name":"Products","IsCategoryRoot":"1","Ancestors":{"BrowseNode":{"BrowseNodeId":"3760901","Name":"Health & Personal Care"}}}}}}}}}]}}}},{"OperationRequest":{"HTTPHeaders":{"0":{"@attributes":{"Name":"UserAgent","Value":"ApaiIO [2.0.0-DEV]"}}},"RequestId":"b9f1bfbf-e54d-413b-b245-64ba721040eb","Arguments":{"Argument":[{"@attributes":{"Name":"AWSAccessKeyId","Value":"AKIAIBYRBZRR7WVI3CMQ"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"AssociateTag","Value":"heyadme-20"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"ItemId"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Operation","Value":"ItemLookup"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"ResponseGroup","Value":"Large"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Service","Value":"AWSECommerceService"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Timestamp","Value":"2015-10-02T18:30:10Z"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Version","Value":"2011-08-01"}},{"@attributes":{"Name":"Signature","Value":"kdOwdicnfDgj6YX6YGHfVdribMtPrXDOBYz6x8fOnM8="}}]},"RequestProcessingTime":"0.0019940000000000"},"Items":{"Request":{"IsValid":"False","ItemLookupRequest":{"IdType":"ASIN","ResponseGroup":"Large","VariationPage":"All"},"Errors":{"Error":{"Code":"AWS.MissingParameters","Message":"Your request is missing required parameters. Required parameters include ItemId."}}}}}]
```

Sorry for such a long json.

Comment: use jsonParse method  like var json = $.jsonParse (response.responseText) , i think you have used in your code this

Comment: you are returning a string from the server side this is why you get first character of the string because string is basically the same array

Comment: May worth a read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#95667

Comment: @ddw147 It says undefined function jsonParse.

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze But JSON.parse will convert it into json. right?

Comment: If you get a string as the json you must parse it first with $.parseJSON(json_string). That will give you the json object you are looking for.

Comment: @Nisthar jsonParse will convert your json to object

Comment: @MarkSkayff Yes. I am getting the json object when i console.log the whole json variable. But when i use json[0] or json[1], it is outputting the character.
I checked the json in jsonlint.com, it says its valid.

Comment: Maybe the json is one big object and not an array? Can you share the output of console.log? And I see you're json.parsing the response twice.

Comment: @ShanShan I edited the question, Note that the json is logged as a string not as a  object.

Comment: Ermmm the JSON string has spammy-ish stuff in there

Answer (score 0):

Please set php return as json some thing like this:

```
 $json = '{}';
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: I may need to return a array of json objects. So may i need to include square bracket around the json?

Comment: Solved. I needed to use:
var restext = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
  var json = JSON.parse(restext);
  console.log(json);

Comment: I don't understand why you have to parse the response twice ?_? And `$.parseJSON` uses `JSON.parse` when it's avalaible in the browser.

Comment: @Nishtar. Probably the first var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText) will give the json object.  Try to console.log(json) that. Don't need to parse it twice.

Comment: Did you tried adding header , so you cant double JSON parse?

Comment: @ji-ruh Yes. I used the double parse function after adding the header.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing.

Syntax
JSON.parse(text[, reviver])

whereas

The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

Here is what I did with your JSON on jsfiddle